# How to make dynamic href's in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I wanted to do the following:

```php
<x-dropdown-link :href="route('userpage', ["user"=> Auth::user()])" wire:navigate>
     {{ __('Profile') }}
</x-dropdown-link>
```

I got an error about an unexpected `endif` but I don't have an `endif` on my file at all!

the solution I found was to use a `wire:click='goto_userpage'` and return the routing code from the `goto_userpage` but `wire:click` is a javascript redirect and doesn't create an actual hyperlink.

Comment: change `["user"=> Auth::user()])` with `['user'=> Auth::user()])` : the double quotes break the attribute value

Comment: That worked, thanks!

seems like I can't accept a comment so I'll jut upvote it!